# Python shell completion using Click `KeyError: 'COMP_WORDS'`

Tags: python, ubuntu, click, pyinstaller, tab-completion

I'm building a simple Python CLI app that uses [Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x), and am trying to enable [shell completion](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/shell-completion/) per the docs.

The app uses Poetry for deps and has no setup.py. To distribute it I want to use PyInstaller to build a binary. Building the binary and running it works fine.

However when I try shell completion, Click is unhappy. For unknown reasons `get_completion_args()` throws `KeyError: 'COMP_WORDS'`, apparently because that env var wasn't present. Why isn't `COMP_WORDS` available?

[minimal repro](https://github.com/onpaws/click-repro)

[GH issue](https://github.com/pallets/click/issues/2326) has more details + logs